How to override the WC_Vars class method of the SEO BY RANK MATH plugin?
I need to override the get_product_price() method, which is located at :wp-content/plugins/seo-by-rank-math/includes/modules/woocommerce/class-wc-vars.php.
I've looked at the documentation, but I'm not sure which hook is correct.

There is no hook. Extend the class on your own and overwrite the function to your needs.

@Snuffy How do I do this? I created a child class, but I can't include it in functions.php, the new class is in the same directory as functions.php, and the path to the original class file is wp-content/plugins/seo-by-rank-math/ includes/modules/woocommerce/class-wc-vars.php
